# Scaffolding the DBContext in Database-first approach recreates the model classes and dbcontext class

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, migration, dbcontext, ef-database-first

I am working on the database first approach in Asp.Net Core. I am using the database first approach and run the scaffolding to create model classes and Dbcontext class.
However, I have multiple project and want to put Dbcontext class in one project while model classes in other projects.

For updating the model classes and dbContext class, when I run the scaffolding (following command) in console, it updates the models and dbcontext but added these stuff again.

````
``` Scaffold-DbContext "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security=True" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -ContextDir "D:\DevReadyNetCoreRepositoryPattern\SampleArchitecture.Infrastructure\Data" -OutputDir "D:\DevReadyNetCoreRepositoryPattern\SampleArchitecture.Core\Entities" -f  ```
````

Comment: Try EF Core Power Tools.

Comment: That does work. Thanks